Lifetime implications of a pointer to a compound literal storing function pointers
I am using the C API of some WIN32 COM objects.
These APIs provide a "subclassing" mechanism by populating a struct containing a vtable, which only consists of function pointers.
What is the lifetime of a compound literal when I assign a pointer to a compound literal to the vtbl member of such a struct.
Here is a short snippet, demonstrating it:
sys->callback = (IXAudio2VoiceCallback) {
    .lpVtbl = &(IXAudio2VoiceCallbackVtbl) {
        .OnBufferEnd = BufferEnded,
        .OnBufferStart = BufferStarted,
        .OnVoiceProcessingPassStart = VoiceProcessStarted,
        .OnVoiceProcessingPassEnd = VoiceProcessEnded,
        .OnLoopEnd = LoopEnded,
        .OnStreamEnd = StreamEnded
    }
};

I need to pass a XAudio2VoiceCallback* to a function.
The lifetime of sys->callback is clearly in my hands, but what about the lifetime of .lpVtbl and it's function pointers?
Is the lifetime static or automatic of the function pointers and lpVtbl ?
